# Evaluating an infinite sum

Tags: maple

In the following code, I can evaluate `S(32)`, but not `S(31)`.

```
restart
sig:=167:
t:=i->exp(-(i^2)/(2*(sig^2)))
S:=l->sum(t(i),i=l..infinity)
```

`evalf(S(32))` evaluates to 177.989, but `evalf(S(31))` just spits back the symbolic formula for `S` (it should evaluate to ~178.972).
I've looked into using [`sum` vs `Sum` with `evalf`](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=evalf%2FSum), but nothing seems to change this behavior. I don't care to see the numerical value for `S(31)`, but Maple can't seem to be able to use it to do anything useful, which is a problem. For example, `plot(S(y),y=20..50)` (when using `sum`) is incomplete.

What is so different between `S(32)` and `S(31)`, and how can I get Maple to evaluate both?

Comment: Does it fail only for S(31) or for all S(2 *n* +1)?

Comment: @AndrewMorton For n in [0..3500], Maple computes `S(n)` except for n in [0..31], n=115,116, and 221. In particular, I'm interested in `S(1)`.

Comment: Have you reported this to Maplesoft? The issue seems to have been fixed in Maple 2016.